# Best practices for React project structure?

Tags: reactjs

I have been doing quite a bit of research into the best way to organize files/ folders for large React applications (using things like custom Hooks, Redux, GraphQl, unit testing, styled-components, etc). I see most people are doing it in slightly different ways. Colocation of files seems like a good idea to me.

But I came across a kind of tradeoff between colocation vs. function-centric organization. If we simply locate all relevant files within a component folder, other developers can easily overlook potentially reusable code and simply rewrite the logic. This is especially a problem when developers are given full responsibility for a particular component/ feature and are not familiar with the entire codebase. It limits the potential for reusability. In such a case it would make sense to have some global folders (e.g. for API interaction logic, utilities, etc.) but this goes towards a more function-centric folder organization.

Has anyone encountered this problem and if so could you share your best practices for a React folder structure?

Comment: Have a look at  [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html). This kind of questions are opinion based, and most likely will be closed.

Comment: Hey alpha, would you recommend anything from your experience after 8 months?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trade-off indeed.  In my experience, it's best to take function-centric organization at the top level as a basis, but put generic code that could be useful in other parts of the application in a separate "common" folder structure.

Having a function-centric organization makes it easier to find everything releated to a certain feature and also to split the application and put some features in a separate one.